# basic fault contract not received correctly in my rest web service using https with ssl and basic authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I am trying to do a basic FaultException in my HTTPS using SSL and basic authentication.
 The problem is when receiving the exception, the client receives the error as WebException... not the FaultException like intended.

I am also overriding a section in my service, not sure if it matters.  The exception I am trying to trap is in the MyServiceAuthorizationManager class.

```
      <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SecureRESTSvcTestBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="EngineAppServiceV001.MyServiceAuthorizationManager, EngineAppServiceV001"/>
```

this is in my IService1.cs

```
    [DataContract]
public class ServiceData
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool Result { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorDetails { get; set; }
}here
```

this is the error section in my MyServiceAuthorizationManager which hits properly

```
                    myServiceData.Result = true;
                myServiceData.ErrorMessage = "this is user error message";
                myServiceData.ErrorDetails = "user error details";
                throw new FaultException<ServiceData>(myServiceData, "user reason error");
```

any ideas why it ALWAYS gets received on client as web exception?

here is how I try and receive on client

```
                catch (FaultException<ServiceData> ex)
            {
                var x1 = ex;
            }
```

Below is my IService1.cs

> ```
> [ServiceContract]
> public interface IService1
> {
>     [OperationContract]
>     [FaultContract(typeof(ServiceData))]
>     [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Login",
>       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
>       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
>       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
>     DataSet Login();
> ```

Now I tried to define fault like this...

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(MyExceptionContainer),Action ="",Name = "MyExceptionContainer", Namespace = "EngineAppServiceV001")]
//[FaultContract(typeof(MyExceptionContainer))]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Login",
  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
DataSet Login();
```

still not working... error message picture attached

[image]

Comment: Please, post your service contract interface.

Comment: Ricardo, I added the Iservice section... any ideas?

Comment: Try to set the FaultContractAttibute like this: [FaultContractAttribute(
        typeof(ServiceData),
        Action = "", 
        Name = "ServiceData", 
        Namespace = "YourNamespace")]

Comment: still doesn't work.  Goes right to WebException in my client.  I made a new datacontract to start from scratch... info posted above.  I tried defining like you mentioned

Comment: Did you rename your ServiceData class to MyExceptionContainer? Does the error happens when you are testing locally?

Comment: yes, I followed a simple tutorial so I just started from scratch.  so that's why you see MyExceptionContainer.  and yes, it happens locally.  I haven't deployed it yet to my web service.  Not sure if I mentioned, I'm also using Https with a certificate.  And using basic authentication by overriding login using  <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="EngineAppServiceV001.MyServiceAuthorizationManager